# Can i copy 'vector' elements in 'set' using the copy algorithm?

Tags: c++

I am getting the run time error in following code. Please let me know can i copy vector elements in set?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    set<int> kk;
    set<int>::iterator itr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(i * 2);
    }
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), inserter(kk, itr));
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are not initialising `itr`:

```
set<int>::iterator itr = kk.begin();
```

Or remove `itr` entirely:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), inserter(kk, kk.begin()));
```

In this instance, you could simply initialise `kk` thus (but if you want to *add to* `kk` follow the line above):

```
set<int> kk(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 18):

If the goal is to **create** a set from the vector elements (rather than update an already existing set that might have some elements in it), then do that, by using the constructor:

```
set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the iterator.

```
set<int>::iterator itr = kk.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(),inserter(kk, kk.end() ));  
                                  // ^^^^^^^^  You need a real iterator.
```